# I am trying to use my Google Sheets data and show to web app as carousel. But the code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, bootstrap-4

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Text Carousel App</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Text Carousel</h1>
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel-inner">
        <!-- The carousel text will be dynamically added here -->
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS (Required for the carousel to work) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>    
      const createCarouselItems = (textData) => {
      const carouselInner = document.getElementById('carousel-inner');
      textData.forEach((row, index) => {
      const text = row.join(', ');
      const activeClass = index === 0 ? 'active' : '';
      const carouselItem = `
        <div class="carousel-item ${activeClass}">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>${text}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>`;
        carouselInner.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', carouselItem);
      });
    };
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createCarouselItems).getTextData();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function getTextData() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Updates');
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3);
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  
  return values;  
}
```

I don't know why the data is not showing (blank) on my web app. I maybe missing something or just need to edit a little for my code to work. I am a newbie in coding and do not know much. I won't get surprised if I find out that what's missing is just a simple line of code. Your help will be greatly appreciated!